# Ich brauche Nachhilfe mit Präpositionen

Tags: preposition, grammatical-case

____dass man im Internet  Informationen zu sehr viele Themen finden kann , nutze ich es oft .

Aber ich liebe auch meine Tageszeitung , weil ______ ______ geschrieben wird, was in meiner Stadt passiert.

So wird ______ hingeweisen wo welche Angebote gibt.

______ ist mir sehr wichtig denn _____ muss Ich mich bäscheftigen.

Präpositionen : darauf , das , darüber , dafür , dafür , damit , dadurch, darin

I have found these examples , but I am not sure which preposition fits the best. Of course I do have some suggestions , but if someone could tell me 100% the right preposition , I would really much appreciate it.

Comment: If your question is ob hold, do not ask a new one, but edit it. It can be reopened. Asking to do or check your homework or similar is not on-topic, though. If you have a specific question and include what you already know and what your problem is, then it is generally ok.

Comment: *Of course I do have some suggestions* – The please tell us what they are and how you arrived at them. We can only help you when we know where to start explaining.